# QGIS to web map with analysis?

Tags: web, qgis

I am developing a web map for a marine conservation charity group.
They want me to use QGIS to clean the data then they want to develop a
web map from that. The webmap needs to have analysis tools such as
clusters, spatio-temporal, and MGET (Marine Geospatial Ecology Tools).
They don't want a Google Map because they want to customize their own
basemap to reflect marine biology (and which I agree with because it
would not be possible to do analysis. In addition, the KML files would
be too large to insert them).

Is there a way to transfer from QGIS to a web map that would be able
to produce analysis such as clusters, spatio-temporal and MGET tools,
and subsetting data?

Answer (score 1):

Processing/cleaning in QGIS and then publishing on a webmap is a common workflow for me.

QGIS allows you to save any layer in geojson format. Which is a format that a mapping library like [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) understands.

See this [leaflet geojson example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)

There are lots of leaflet plugins to do certain kinds of analysis / visualizations. e.g. [marker clustering](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

So, if your datasets are relatively small, you can just export "raw" data as geojson from QGIS, then use the plugins to cluster, etc.

However, if the analysis is complex, or your data is very large, you might prefer to do the analysis upfront in QGIS, and then export the post-processed layers as geojson, and load those into Leaflet (or whatever mapping library you choose).

Comment: would it be possible to send me an example workflow that you have done? (I tried messaging you but I didn't see an option). I believe I might have to go with the second option since my data is very large

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't send you an example workflow, because my "workflow" is not a script, it's a human process involving code, clicking, and googling.  As far as code, you can see an example leaflet map here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html. Once you have what you want in QGIS, it's largely "just" a matter of saving your layers as geojson, popping them in the map and styling. Most importantly you have to have a clear understanding of what you want your end result to be, start there.